# Function to create a string from an array (Mathematica)

Tags: arrays, string, function, wolfram-mathematica

I'm a newbie in Mathematica programming and I need some help. I'm trying to write a function that gets the elements of an arbitrary array and builds a string especifically formatted to use in Math LibreOffice.

My code is as follows:

```
OOForm[MM_] :=
   (strMM = "left ( matrix{";
   For[i = 1, i < Dimensions[MM][[1]], i++] {  (* not last row *)   
      For[j = 1, j < Dimensions[MM][[2]], j++] { (* not last element from the row *)    
         strMM = strMM <> ToString[MM[[i, j]], InputForm] <> "#";
      }; (* last element from the row *) 
      strMM = strMM <> ToString[MM[[i, Dimensions[MM][[2]]]], InputForm] <> "##"; 
   };
   For[j = 1, j < Dimensions[MM][[2]], j++] { (* last row without the last element *) 
      strMM = strMM <> ToString[MM[[Dimensions[MM][[1]], j]], InputForm] <> "#";
   }; (* last element *)
   strMM = strMM <> ToString[MM[[(Dimensions[MM][[1]]), Dimensions[MM][[2]]]], InputForm] <> "} right )";
strMM;
)
```

With an input like:

```
A = {{3/2, -1, -2, -2, -2}, {0, 3, 6, 10, 14}, {-6, 3/2, 5, 5, 5}, {19/2, -7, -35/2, -24, -61/2}};
```

The expected output is:

```
"left ( matrix{3/2#-1#-2#-2#-2##0#3#6#10#14##-6#3/2#5#5#5##19/2#-7#-35/2#-24#-61/2} right )"
```

But it throws this output:

```
"left ( matrix{-61/2#-61/2##-61/2#-61/2} right )"
```

This is not the expected output, but I'm not able to find the error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First get a string representing your array.

I hate single-letter variable names, and I follow the Mathematica convention of using an initial lower-case letter for the variable names I define) so let

```
myArray = {{3/2, -1, -2, -2, -2}, {0, 3, 6, 10, 14}, {-6, 3/2, 5, 5, 5}, {19/2, -7, -35/2, -24, -61/2}};
```

then

```
myArrayString = ToString[myArray,InputForm];
```

and

```
StringReplace[myArrayString,{" " -> "", "," -> "#", "{{" -> "left ( matrix{", "}}"
 -> "} right)", "}" -> "#", "{" -> ""}]
```

returns the string you want.

If you want a function to do this, just smash it all together like this:

```
ooForm[arr_List]:= StringReplace[ToString[arr,InputForm],
     {" " -> "", "," -> "#", "{{" -> "left ( matrix{", "}}"
     -> "} right)", "}" -> "#", "{" -> ""}]
```

You made a basic error common to newcomers to Mathematica. Using loops is a sure sign that you are writing imperative, procedural code which is almost always an inefficient use of your time (note that the code I've written is much shorter than the code you wrote, and uses fewer functions) and an inefficient use of your computer's time.  The latter is much less important, of course, but if you are interested compare the time taken by your approach and by mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that works great. And you are right, I tried to port the C style programming to Mathematica, just that. :)